# Awk script doesn't run, seems like I've skipped brackets, but I've counted them, their number is even

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I'm writing an awk script into ubuntu terminal. But it doesn't start to work. It seems like I've 
overlooked something of these: "", '', (, ), {, }, but I've counted each symbol like these and their 
count is even.
So I really don't understand where I'm failed with these script

(preface, I've written cal > database/calendar.txt)
the pseudocode of scipt for easier understanding of script itself:
// first I get current day and current week day from the system 
// then I make calendar.txt to be one line, with one space between fields (in awk terminology) 
// then I firstly find current week day (monday and so on) 
// then I find current day (16,17 and so on) 
// after all, I equate found values to variables (resulted_day and resulted_week_day) 
after all I'm trying to start it, unfortunately it doesn't work
there is no output at all, script just is waiting input further commands, like if I overlooked a bracket or something like that

script:

```
awk -v day_searched="$(date +%"d")" -v week_day_searched="$(date +"%a")" 
'BEGIN{FS=" ";RS="NOT_EXISTING_dELIMITER"} {
current_field = 0
resulted_day = "not_found_yet"
resulted_week_day= "not_found_yet"
max_file_lenght = 100

while (current_field < max_file_lenght) {
  if ($(current_field) == week_day_searched) {
    resulted_week_day = $(current_field)
  }
  current_field++
}

current_field_second = 0

while (current_field_second < max_file_lenght) {
  if ($(current_field_second) == day_searched) {
    resulted_day = $(current_field_second) }
  curent_field_second++
  }
printf "TOday is %s %s March", resulted_week_day, resulted_day}' database/calendar.txt
```

Comment: I see some typos (`curent_field_second++`) and something that is probably wrong (`current_field = 0 ... if ($(current_field) == week_day_searched) ... current_field++`). You do know what `$0` means in awk, right? Fixing that typo at least makes the program stop.

Comment: FYI in a POSIX awk `RS="NOT_EXISTING_dELIMITER"` will set `RS` to the character `N`. If you're using an awk that supports multi-char RS then `RS="^$"` is the way to set RS to a value that doesn't exist in the input. If not then `RS="\0"` might be close enough.

Comment: Also, `date +"%a"` outputs `Fri` and `cal` `Fr`.

Comment: And this will never match: `if ($(current_field_second) == day_searched)` as `cal` probably colors todays date and if you look at it with `hexdump -C` or such, you'll see this: `5f 08 31 5f 08 37  ...  _.1_.7`.

Comment: @JamesBrown , yes I fixed misspelling (current instead of curent), and replaced "%a" to %"a"
Now it works, but day_searched equals not found yet in the end of script

Comment: @JamesBrown what should I do to match current day with real today's day ? can you told me it?

Comment: Remove the special characters `cal` created to the file and try it then.

Comment: @JamesBrown sorry man, I'm disappointed, I googled how to off color in cal command, I can't find this. And when I write cat calendar.txt, there is only calendar, not color symbols and so on. Ohh, so hard

Comment: This is not your only issue but check what `date +"%a"` returns and what is in `cal`.

Comment: Put this in the beginning to remove special chars  `gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/,"")`. Not in the `BEGIN`, tho.

Comment: "*no output at all, It just is offering me to input further commands, like if I've forgotten a bracket for example*" -- A missing bracket in your awk code would be a syntax error, and would result in an error message from awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your awk as base:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=" "
    RS=""                                            # read upto an empty record
}
{
    gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/,"")                         # remove special chars reading file
    current_field = 1                                # start from 1
    resulted_day = "not_found_yet"
    resulted_week_day= "not_found_yet"
    # max_file_lenght = 100                          # use NF instead

    week_day_searched=substr(week_day_searched,1,2)  # take only 2 first chars of weekday

    while (current_field <= NF) {
        if ($current_field ==week_day_searched) {
            resulted_week_day = $current_field
        }
        current_field++
    }

    current_field_second = 1                         # start from 1

    while (current_field_second <= NF) {
        if ($current_field_second == day_searched) { 
            resulted_day = $current_field_second }
        current_field_second++                       # fix typo
    }
    printf "TOday is %s %s March\n", resulted_week_day, resulted_day
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -v day_searched="$(date +"%d")" -v week_day_searched="$(date +"%a")" -f program.awk file
TOday is Sa 18 March
```

`cal` produces special chars (at least for me, current date is highlighted, check out the 18th below):

```
$ cal | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 41 70 72  69 6c 20 32 30 32 30 20  |     April 2020 |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 0a 53  75 20 4d 6f 20 54 75 20  |      .Su Mo Tu |
00000020  57 65 20 54 68 20 46 72  20 53 61 20 20 0a 20 20  |We Th Fr Sa  .  |
00000030  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  31 20 20 32 20 20 33 20  |        1  2  3 |
00000040  20 34 20 20 0a 20 35 20  20 36 20 20 37 20 20 38  | 4  . 5  6  7  8|
00000050  20 20 39 20 31 30 20 31  31 20 20 0a 31 32 20 31  |  9 10 11  .12 1|
00000060  33 20 31 34 20 31 35 20  31 36 20 31 37 20 5f 08  |3 14 15 16 17 _.|
00000070  31 5f 08 38 20 20 0a 31  39 20 32 30 20 32 31 20  |1_.8  .19 20 21 |
00000080  32 32 20 32 33 20 32 34  20 32 35 20 20 0a 32 36  |22 23 24 25  .26|
00000090  20 32 37 20 32 38 20 32  39 20 33 30 20 20 20 20  | 27 28 29 30    |
000000a0  20 20 20 20 0a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |    .           |
000000b0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 0a              |           .|
000000bc
```